# Which Model is better in R?

Tags: r, regression

I've performed linear regression on two different combination of variables.
First combination gives Multiple R-Squared Value greater than the one in second combination.
Second combination gives Adjusted R-Squared Value greater than the one in first combination.So I'm confused to find the better model of these two.
Can anybody help me in this?

**Below is the image of First model**
[image]

**Below is the image of Second model**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Model 2 is more parsimonious and the R^2 is insignificantly smaller than the first model. The adjusted R^2 takes into account the fact that fewer degrees of freedom are needed to get to this level of model performance, so if we are restricted to only this amount of information the decision shoul be in favor of the seoncd model. This of course has very little to do with science, since we have been given absolutely no information about the data-gathering process.